# problema com duplicidade do formulário

Tags: php, html

Estou tendo um problema muito comum, e não sei como resolver. Vou pastar uma página em php bem simples para explicar.

O problema ocorre quando o usuário submete o formulário, e quando ele clica na detinha de voltar do navegador, o formulário e submetido novamente, gerando uma duplicidade no BD. Tem alguma forma de tratar isso?

Segue o código do meu formulário:

```
<?php
//======================================================================================================================
// Envia formulário
//======================================================================================================================
if ((!empty($action)) and ($action === "add")) {

    // Recebe dados do formulario
    $nome = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
    $idade = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'idade', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));

    // Verifica se informou os dados
    if ((empty($nome)) || (empty($idade))) {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('ERRO. Iforme todos os dados'); 
            history.back();
        </script>
        <?php
        die;
    }

    // Registra no BD
    $inserir1 = Query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO cadastro VALUES ('0', '$nome', '$idade')");

    // Verifica se cadastrou
    if ($inserir1) {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('ERRO. Iforme todos os dados'); 
            window.location='cadastro.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('ERRO. Tente mais tarde'); 
            history.back();
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
//======================================================================================================================
?>


<form name='form'  onsubmit='return validacao()' method=post action='cadastro.php?action=add' >

    <input  type="text" name="nome">
    <input  type="text" name="idade">

    <input type="submit" name="finalizar">
</form>
```

Comment: quando salvas os dados no banco de dados, podes fazer um `reset` completo, redireccionando com a função `header` seguido de um `exit`. E deves também preparar o banco de dados para que não cadastre réplicas.

Comment: Quando verifica se cadastrou no if else só retorna alert com erro? Pode isso Arnaldo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dessa forma quando clicar na setinha voltar do navegador o session impedirá de reenviar o formulário e ser submetido novamente.

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 ...............
 ...............
  if ($_SESSION["nome"]==""){
   $inserir1 = Query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO cadastro VALUES ('0', '$nome', '$idade')");
   $_SESSION["nome"] = $_POST["nome"];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma comum para resolver esse problema é redirecionar o usuário pra própria página para limpar os dados do post:

```
//antes de qualquer saída (echo, caracteres etc)
//ao invés do window.location
header('Location:cadastro.php');
```

No seu caso você também deve verificar se a requisição é POST ou GET antes de processar o resultado:

```
if (!empty($_POST) && !empty($action) && $action === "add") {
    ...
```

Comment: Dessa forma seria ideal, o problema e que antes do `header('Location:cadastro.php');` eu ja executo alguns `echo`.

Comment: sa segunda forma `(!empty($_POST)` não resolve muito, pois se o usuário volta o browser manda o formulário via POST.